# phonegap google maps with framework7 v2

Tags: google-maps, phonegap, html-framework-7, phonegap-gmaps-plugin

i am having a serious problem working with [phonegap google maps](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/) with [Framework7 esp v2](http://framework7.io/docs/),

I am required to select a div in my HTML to place a map here is what i did:

HTML:
[image]
[image]

JavaScript:
[image]

There is more logic to the JS file but on my android device when i open this page i am getting the page overlapping the map.

**THE MAP IS RENDERED BUT IS NOT REPLACING THE ORIGINAL HTML**

[image: How it is in F7 v2]

**And here how it looked in F7 v1**
[image: v1 model]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to understand how this plugin displays the map.
This plugin generates the native map view under the browser, and the browser is going to be `transparent`.
[image]

When you open the new page, the previous page is under the current page in HTML hierarchy.
[image]

However, the map view is NOT html element, the map view is displayed under the previous page.
[image]

Thus, solution is, you just add a CSS rule.

```
.page-previous {
    display: none;
}
```

[image]

https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/2164

Special thanks to [wf9a5m75](https://stackoverflow.com/users/697856/wf9a5m75)

Answer (score 0):

But, why would you like to display your text on the map canvas, you want to then display a button on the map canvas ?

Because, if you want to display a button, create custom controls https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#Adding_Controls_to_the_Map

```
var deleteAllButton = document.getElementById('deleteAllButton');
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM].push(deleteAllButton);
```

If it's a simple text, put it here

```
<div id="map" oncontextmenu="return false"></div>
<p>Your text</p>
```

And then use position: absolute

Comment: actually thats where the error is, i dont want that whole grey background to appear at all, there has to be the map on all that area

Comment: So, you wanna display text ("the map canvas") on the map canvas area but a grey background appear ? (sorry if I don't understand everything, i'm French)
On my project, I display textDiv over my map canvas: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RIfABkRrUN-0FKcJF3S4paHIQvFdIXDX/view
My textDiv isn't in my map div, but I managed to put the text over the map canvas with a 'position: absolute; bottom: 70px;'

Comment: i want to remove tht text and that background as well, only the map is supposed to be there, in F7 v1 we didnt have that problem

Comment: Remove "the map canvas" in your map div ??
It's displayed although your text isn't in a <p>

Comment: that text was to check whats showing on the grey area, after initialising the map all that has to disappear and leave only the map

Comment: My english is pretty bad, you mean your problem's solved?

Comment: i get you, no the problem is still there, as long as that text and grey area are there, the problem is there until when we are left with the map only

Comment: https://free.mailbigfile.com/download_from_cloud.php?file_id=15890753&retrieval_token=121f11429b009fec808f59530bde00df


Its supposed to look like that